# How to USE Setasign/FPDI In laravel 5 Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to USE Setasign/FPDI In laravel 5 Project

How to Set `App.php`?

I user composer download it and don't know how to use it

Comment: The same way you would in a non-laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Install with composer as described:
https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI

Then...

```
$pdf = new \FPDF('portrait','mm', 'A4');
```

If you need Fpdi:

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
```